# Validate if input is in dd.mm.yyyy format in batch file

Tags: validation

I have a batch file which takes two input. one is server name and another is Date. i want the user to force to input the date in dd.mm.yyyy format.

How can i do so?

Any help will be appriciated.

-KAKA-

Comment: Code? Data input example? Language?

Answer (score 0):

You could check this jQuery plugin : http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
Then you could do this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#date").mask("99.99.9999");
});
```